# I want to define an upstart process without any fork. Do I need to specify 'expect'?

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

In order to define an upstart process, to be started automatically when the system is started in Ubuntu 12.04, I found a [useful page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto) describing how to create a `myservice.conf` file. The given example has the line

```
expect fork
```

to be used when the process is forked exactly once. But my process is not forked whatsoever. Can I just omit this 'stanza/parameter'?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must omit expect if your process's main process will stay resident. The default behavior without expect is to track the process using a simple `waitpid` call.